# Secure file transfer over unstable internet

Tags: ftp

I have a router with own IP-address and a ubuntu 16.04 server running samba. Normally I VPN to the router and connect to my files through 'Map Network Drive' in Win10. But I need a solution to use, when I am at a place with unstable and unsecure internet. I guess that SFTP could be a solution, but are unsure, if that is safe enough, when I use public open wifi? I need a solution that supports:

1. Large files (up to 10 gb)
2. Are able to resume a download, if connection is reestablished, without starting from the beginning of the file
3. Are secure - both for my home network and for my files being transferred.

Which solution should I research?

Comment: I think SFTP is what you're looking for.

Comment: But dont sftp use ssh? I've heard you should not expose ssh over the internet

Comment: No matter what you use, you will always have to expose a port of your server to the internet. If you set it up correctly you shouldn't need to worry about it. That is: Prefer keyfile authentication over password, limit number of authentication attempts, that kind of thing. By the way, what prevents you from using a VPN when you have an "unstable and unsecure internet"?

Comment: Something have to be opened of course, either for sftp, or a webserver or some other solution. Therefore I'm seeking the advice of all you smart guys, that knows way more about security than me :-)

Comment: After I put up the question, I found out that I could combine VPN and SFTP and this seems to work. However the speed is very low. Is that because of the VPN?